# How to extract hour from timestamp?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have taken only the time value from systimestamp. But with the same i need to extract hour from time value.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'hh24:mi:ss'')) FROM DUAL ;
```

but I'm getting "invalid extract field for extract source"

Comment: By simply using SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;  i'm getting hour with timezone_hour. But I need without timezone_hour

Comment: Use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `systimestamp` or - `CAST(systimestamp AS timestamp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `to_char` as follows:

```
SELECT to_char(systimestamp,'hh24') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: hi it works. But my input date with time value will be like this. Eg. '02/04/2021 12:55:02' . from this i need to extract hour value.

Comment: So what is the data type of your input?  Looks to me like it is a string, not a date or timestamp.

Comment: Yes ..It is a string..How to extract hour and min from a string input

Comment: `to_char(to_date('02/04/2021 12:55:02', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh24')`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're converting your timestamp to a character, which means it doesn't have an hour value for you to extract.

Try taking systimestamp out of the function.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM systimestamp) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This gives hour value with timezone hour. But i need without timezone hour